# Django REST - saving and serializers in case of foreign fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I think this question will be duplicated, but I am lost googling and reading [the doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-relational-fields) on Django serializers. And still I failed to implement the simplest goal of saving serialized objects that correspond to models that are related by one-to-many relationship.

Here's the mock code:

The models:

```
class ParentModel(models.Model)
    # Some fields

class ChildModel(models.Model)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(ParentModel, models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Serializers:

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ('__all__')
```

Basically, I can't figure out two things:

1. How do I define the child-serializer to reflect its relationship with parent
2. How do I implement the respective post-request:

The class-view:

```
class ChildList(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        parent_serializer = ParentSerializer(data = request.data)
        if parent_serializer.is_valid():
           # how do I tell the child serializer to use parent serializer and save?
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare separate serializer for `ParentModel`

e.g.

```
class ParentModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ParentModel


class ChildModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    parent = ParentModelSerializer()        

    class Meta:
        model = ChildModel
```

then, you must handle creation adn update of ChildModelSerilizer by yourself: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations